# Tell YUI compressor to preserve my debugger; statements

Tags: debugging, yui-compressor

I'm trying to use the `debugger;` statement to debug JS in Firefox, but YUI Compressor is interfering.

A complete pause of Firefox does not occur in uncompressed files, but in compressed files. For debugging, I want to use the `debugger;` statement, since setting breakpoints manually is impossible when YUI puts everything neatly into a single line.

Now, YUI remvoes the `debugger;` statement from source.

Is there a way to preserve the `debugger;` statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

> eval('debugger;');

Comment: that is genious, eval is the answer. eval any unique string, don't even need to be debugger. Evaluating debugger does not work the same, as the `debugger` statement will trigger in its own, now useless, scope. With no call stack. But it is easy to search the source for that string, as it will not be anywhere else and add breakpoints :)

Comment: It's a little rough, but for me browsers do maintain the call stack. You just have to hit `step out` once or twice and the debug tools will take you to the `eval()` statement